# Android PhoneGap HTML5video

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-video, cordova-plugins

I am looking for an HTML 5 video plugin for `PhoneGap`.

I found a plugin at [GitHub](https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5video) but there maybe something wrong as I have the following issues:

- I don't know where to place the `plugin.xml`
- I don't know how to to link with it `<video>` tag
- and it's not working with `PhoneGap`

this javascript function now

```
function start(){
    window.plugins.html5video.initialize({"video1" : "movie.mp4"});
    window.plugins.html5video.play("video1");
}
```

`04-24 09:52:59.305: E/Web Console(740): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'initialize' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:44`

Comment: Please fix github url is broken.

Comment: https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5video @madlymad

Comment: Are you using `PhoneGap` or `Cordova`? the plugin you posted is for `Cordova`. Can you add more info to your question what have you tried when you get that log. Is the video online or offline?

Comment: i place my video in res/raw/movie.mp4 and i used Cordova2.9.jar and Cordova.js

Comment: kindly see pic http://i61.tinypic.com/2h64jzc.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After several attempts I solved this way:

- I have installed `Git`
- I have installed the plugin [HTML5Video](https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video) for Cordoba with command `cordova plugin add https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video.git` (with this command, the project has run automatically configured to use the plugin)
- I created the folder `platforms\androis\res\raw\` where I copied the video `splash.mp4`
- In the html file (in my case `\www\splash.html`) I insert this code in HEAD:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Html5Video.js"></script>
  <script>
      // Wait for device API libraries to load
      //
      function onLoad() {
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      }

      // device APIs are available
      //
      function onDeviceReady() {
          window.plugins.html5Video.initialize({
              "splashvideo" : "splash.mp4"
          })
          window.plugins.html5Video.play("splashvideo");
      }
  </script>
  ```

and this is the BODY code

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <video id="splashvideo" autobuffer controls="false"></video>
</body>
```

It's work for me ;)

Comment: Excellent! Then...rate me, rate me :D

Comment: vote up required 15 reputation :( . and i have only 14 as i reached 15 reputation. i will definately up :)

Comment: Right! So remember me when you get 15 reputation hahaha ;)

Comment: But is still not showing the video, just loading icon on the middle of video

Comment: I have same issue, where on android device i see the video icon/control but it doesn't play

Comment: The video was successfully converted to mp4? Normally the device (outside the app) played video?
You have enabled hardware acceleration? https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video#enable-hardware-acceleration-in-androidmanifestxml